# Easier way to search all directions of a 2D list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a function for a game of Othello/Reversi that I'm writing, and I thought that it was very inefficient.

So basically, there is a game board with a user-set number of rows and columns (with row 1 starting at the top, column 1 starting at the left).

```
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . W W W . . . .
 . . . . B B . . . .
 . . . . B B B W . .
 . . . . . . . B . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
```

B represents black, and holds the integer 1.
W represents white, and holds the integer 2.
An empty space holds the integer 0.

So boardArray[7][7] would return the value 1. (8th row, 8th column)

I'm writing a function that checks the validity of a user inputted move. Let's say Player Black wants to insert his piece into Row 9, Column 5. Starting from that location, the program must check in all directions (north, northeast, east, southeast, etc) to see if a black piece is found. If found, it will then check if there is a white piece in between the two black pieces. If a white piece is found, that white piece turns to a black piece.

Currently, I'm attempting this in a painstakingly inefficient way.

```
    #north
    x = 1
    while True:
        try:
            if boardArray[row-x][col] == 0:
                break
            elif boardArray[row-x][col] == self._playerTurn:
                #function that flips all pieces in between the user inputted location and the location of the same-color piece found
        except IndexError:
            break
        x += 1


    #northeast
    x = 1
    while True:
        try:
            if boardArray[row-x][col+x] == 0:
                break
            elif boardArray[row-x][col+x] == self._playerTurn:
                #function that flips all pieces in between the user inputted location and the location of the same-color piece found
        except IndexError:
            break
        x += 1


    #east
    x = 1
    while True:
        try:
            if boardArray[row][col+x] == 0:
                break
            elif boardArray[row][col+x] == self._playerTurn:
                #function that flips all pieces in between the user inputted location and the location of the same-color piece found
        except IndexError:
            break
        x += 1
```

etc.

1. Can anyone advise me on a more efficient way to accomplish this?
2. What would be a good way to store the locations of the pieces we must flip?

Hopefully this post makes sense! It'd be easier to understand if you know the rules of the game Othello.

Thank you beforehand! - Python Newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing out the loops 8 times for the 8 directions you need to search in, I'd suggest using a loop over a list of direction vectors (2-tuples, probably) that specify the amount to increment the row and column coordinates. You could also use a `for` loop on a `range`, rather than a `while` loop to handle the distance you're moving along the direction vector.

Here's some code that should find and flip all appropriate spaces. I've not actually tested the code, since I don't have the rest of the game logic to wrap it in, but it should be close to working:

```
toflip = []
for x, y in [(0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,-1), (-1,-1), (-1,0), (-1,1)]: # directions
    try:
        potential_flips = []
        for d in range(1,10):  # distances
            if boardArray[row+y*d][col+x*d] == self._playerTurn: # friendly piece found
                toflip.extend(potential_flips)
                break
            elif boardArray[row+y*d][col+x*d] == 3-self._playerTurn: # other player's piece
                potential_flips.append((col+x*d, row+y*d))
            else: # empty square found, give up on this direction
                break
    except IndexError: # ran off an edge of the board before finding a friendly piece
        pass
if toflip: # valid move, causes some of the opponents pieces to be flipped
    for x, y in toflip:
        boardArray[y][x] = self._playerTurn
else: # invalid move, doesn't flip anything
    raise ValueError("invalid move") # or report an error code some other way
```

You could probably change the logic to directly flip the items from the `potential_flips` list when you find the friendly piece, rather than storing them in a top-level list and flipping them all later. However, you'll then need different logic to detect invalid moves (which don't flip anything).